# Coding Bat CigarParty Ternary Operator Solution

Tags: java

```
public boolean cigarParty(int cigars, boolean isWeekend) {
  if (isWeekend == false) {
    return cigars >= 40 && cigars <= 60 ? true : false;
  }
  if (cigars >= 40) {
    return isWeekend ? true : false;
  }
  else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Does anyone have any feedback on how I could be more efficient with ternary operators?

Comment: When the code reaches `if (cigars >= 40)` it is always the case that `isWeekend == true` - so the following return statement can be simplified to `return true`.  You could then simplify the `if..else` to just `return (cigars >= 40);`

Answer (score 0):

These ternary operators can be removed entirely. Each of your return statements already evaluates to the required boolean result. Your statements as written with the ternary operators essentially say: `if true return true, else return false`, which is redundant.

I think the most readable form that includes a ternary operator, if that's what's needed, is:

```
public boolean cigarParty(int cigars, boolean isWeekend) {
    if (cigars < 40){
        return false;
    }
    return isWeekend ? true : cigars <= 60;
}
```

This also eliminates the repeated comparison of `cigars` with `40`.

Answer (score 0):

As @codebod said, much of your code is redundant.

This is one way to solve it with ternary operators:

```
public boolean cigarParty(int cigars, boolean isWeekend) {
    return (isWeekend) ? (cigars >= 40): (cigars >= 40 && cigars <= 60);
}
```

This is one way to solve it without ternary operators:

```
public boolean cigarParty(int cigars, boolean isWeekend) {
    if (isWeekend){
        return (cigars >= 40);
    }else{
        return (cigars >= 40 && cigars <= 60);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need ternary operators at all. But you can do it like so.

- if the `cigars < 40`, it is always `false`.
- otherwise, return `true` if either of the subsequent conditions are true.

```
public static boolean cigarParty(int cigars, boolean isWeekend) {
    return cigars < 40 ? false : (cigars <= 60 || isWeekend);
}
```

I would prefer the following:

- if `cigars < 40` it will return `false` and short circuit the expression.
- if either of the others is `true` it will return `true`

```
public static boolean cigarParty(int cigars, boolean isWeekend) {
    return cigars >= 40 && (cigars <= 60 || isWeekend);
}
```